# BigInteger's .equals() method is not working correctly

Tags: java

So recently, I've tried dabbling with dynamic programming with the Fibonacci sequence. (With `BigInteger`s)

No matter what number I put in, it overflows.
Even 1 (which I really do not understand.)

So from what I see, it appears that lines 18 - 20 are not running for some reason.

I've even tried to make it throw a `RuntimeException` inside the if conditional, but the program never crashes from a `RuntimeException`. It always crashes from a `StackOverflowError`, which means lines 18 - 20 never ran. (It also means that I'll always have a `StackOverflowError` because my recursion never ends.)

What did I do wrong?

```
package cos.view;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Fibonacci {

    static BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");
    static BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");
    static BigInteger three = new BigInteger("3");
    static BigInteger testNumber = new BigInteger("5");
    static HashMap<BigInteger, BigInteger> map = new HashMap<BigInteger, BigInteger>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(fibonacci(testNumber, map));
    }

    public static BigInteger fibonacci(BigInteger n, HashMap<BigInteger, BigInteger> map) {
        if (n.equals(0) || n.equals(1)) {
            return n;
        }

        if (map.containsKey(n)) {
            return map.get(n);
        }

        map.put(n.subtract(one), fibonacci(n.subtract(one), map));
        map.put(n.subtract(two), fibonacci(n.subtract(two), map));

        BigInteger nMinusOne = map.get(n.subtract(one));
        BigInteger nMinusTwo = map.get(n.subtract(two));

        BigInteger sumValue = nMinusOne.add(nMinusTwo);
        map.put(n, sumValue);

        return sumValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing a `BigInteger` with an `int` will always `false` since they are not the same type.

You need to compare two `BigInteger`:

```
if(n.equals(BigInteger.ZERO) || n.equals(BigInteger.ONE)){
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation for [BigInteger.equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Returns:
>       true if and only if the specified Object is a BigInteger whose value is numerically equal to this BigInteger.

Change the way of comparing elements:

```
if(n.equals(BigInteger.ZERO) || n.equals(BigInteger.ONE)){
    return n;
}
```